# Select first children in nested list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select only the first children under Sally. Using JavaScript, how would I select Car, Boat, & Bike and change the font color to red?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j('#content2 ul li ul').children().css('color', '#ff0000');
});
</script>

<div id="content2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Bob</li>
                <li>Sally
                    <ul>
                        <li>Car</li>
                        <li>Boat</li>
                        <li>Bike
                            <ul>
                                <li>Red</li>
                                <li>Green</li>
                                <li>Blue</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Larry</li>
               <li>Mo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste your JavaScript code.

Comment: Can you work with a library like jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ )?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  j('#content2 ul li ul').children().css('color', '#ff0000');
 });
 </script>

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` will select elements based on a CSS selector, so one way would be:

```
var elements = document.querySelector('#content2 > div > div > ul > li > ul > li');
```

Oh, you've got jQuery. Then you just need to be a little more specific, because descendants will be matched by default:

```
j('#content2 > div > div > ul > li > ul > li').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: This also selects red, green, and blue and changes them red. I want them to remain unchanged.

Comment: @MattWallace: No, they just inherit their style from their parent. Style them to default to `color: black` with CSS, or something.